# html images appearing in wrong places

Tags: html, css, e-commerce

I am designing a [bigcartel](http://bigcartel.com/) website and am receiving a weird browser-specific problem, on chrome, mozilla and some other browsers when on the website images on the products and the home page do not load correctly and are either slightly above or below where they should be. It is resolved by reloading a couple of times but obviously that isn't good. Here is the link to the website, and the source html replaces bigcartel variables so here is a whole .zip containing all page html and theme css.

https://mega.co.nz/#!aMoTEAwJ!CM6ZLyTMiY8YGWg3StH0xFNVNb89M2WTLkJ0khR-np8